# Unicode text doesn't appear correctly in shell

Tags: bash, shell, gnome-terminal, kali-linux

I'm using the terminal in Kali Linux and I try to type Arabic text the characters are shown but separated (appearance not correct)

This what my shell shows me ex. لا ا ل ه ا لا ا ل ل ه,
which should be لا اله الا الله

### can the shell support Unicode text

the output of command ps $$ $PPID; locale

```
 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3777 ?        Sl     0:15 gnome-terminal
 6092 pts/1    Ss     0:00 bash
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

it seems it is utf-8 ok

**can i change the font used for shell output to another font? and where the fonts located?**

Comment: You should add the shell and the terminal emulator you are using. So it will be easier for someone to help you find an answer.

Comment: what do you mean by add shell >> if you mean the shell type so it is the terminal shell shipped with kali linux

Comment: I don't know what Kali's default terminal is. Run `ps $$ $PPID; locale` in a terminal and copy-paste the output into your question. Do you observe problems with other characters (Latin with accents, Chinese, Hebrew, …)?

Comment: FYI, all terminals are fixed-width, character-cell based. A good unicode terminal, such as rxvt-unicode can do combining, but only if they are present in the source.

Comment: is there a solution for this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Id don't know much about gnome-terminal, but if you're going to work with non-latin scripts, you may want to look at [rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html).  It handles almost every script correctly (provided you have the fonts, and the output really is UTF-8).

```
$ sudo apt-get install rxvt-unicode
$ urxvt
```

As a bonus, you'll get a great piece of documentation about terminals reachable by [`man 7 urxvt`](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/doc/rxvt.7.pod) which is also nice place to look for troubleshooting information.

Note that in default configuration Rxvt looks quite unappealing (it tries to be nice to xterm users :)) so search Internet or mentioned FAQ for how to make it look better.

Other task is selecting the right font.  For Urxvt, it's `font` resource.  For experimenting, you can specify the font name on command line, e.g. `urxvt -fn "xft:Dejavu Serif".  Refer to urxvt documentation for this.

If you want to look for fonts, I'd start by searching in your repository. For example `aptitude search arabic` or `apt-cache search arabic` does this in Debian.

Comment: same problem !! i think this because of the font type >> how to change the font for both uxrvt and terminal in gnome

Comment: After some quick looks, Arabic seems quite challenging to get to work properly on any terminal (it has complicated compose rules, RTL direction and much more) and I don't have time to study Urxvt docs to find out (if it is even possible).  So TBH this is my limit for now. :)  I myself would be interested in how to do it.

Comment: no problem for direction of the text>> so now can i change the font of the terminal

Answer (score 1):

#### Terminal fonts

In a ***terminal*** you have to use so called *`monospaces`* fonts, (where a lower caps `i` use same width than a upper case `w`):

(Thats monospaced fonts:

```
iiiiiiii
WWWWWWWW
```

Thats normal fonts:

> iiiiiiii
>
> WWWWWWWW

)

This is because all tables and output formating is done by character positionning.

So maybe your ouput could be prompted by using a *dialog tool*:

```
mytext='لا اله ال'
gdialog --infobox "$mytext" 60 2
```

Comment: search on google for *`arabic monospaced font`*

Comment: under Debian, you could  `apt-get install fonts-hosny-thabit`. This packet hold *fixed width OpenType Arabic fonts*

Answer (score 0):

Use `setxkbmap`:

```
setxkbmap -layout ara -variant basic
```

If you want, add this line to your `~/.xinitrc` file to run it every boot.

Comment: same problem !! the characters appeared separated